# Realm Swift inverse relationships many-to-many

Tags: swift, realm

I'm currently trying to work out the best way to architect my realm objects for ease of retrieval.

I have 2 objects `tags` and `object` there are multiple `tags` and each one might contain many `object`. Similarly each `object` could have multiple `tag` associated with it

Ideally selecting a single tag should retrieve all `object` that have at least that one tag (but could obviously have multiple)

would my models be specified as

```
class Tag: Object {
    let objects = List<Object>()
}

class Object {
    let tags = List<Tag>()
}
```

I don't think I need to use an inverse relationship here or should I? Choosing a Category I should be able to just retrieve a list of all object references regardless, but then maintaining and updating the references to an object might be difficult here? I.e a user selects tag 'A' then updates the first object to also include tag 'B' I would need to update the object in the List for Tag A, then add a new item to the list for Tag 'B' and finally update the actual Object itself to include Tag 'B' in it's list of tags.

Just to be clear an Object will only ever display and allow editing of it's `Tag` objects. But the Tag object itself will need to know what `Object`'s are applicable to it.

However it feels like I will have to do multiple updates when ideally I'd like to minimise this effort. Can anyone recommend a better way to do this? Or is there no way around this due to the limitations of Realm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is exactly what `LinkingObjects` is for. Changing the `objects` property in `Tag` to `let objects = LinkingObjects(fromType: Object.self, property: "tags")` will make it automatically update whenever a tag is added to an object.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I took so long to accept. I was writing unit tests to test this out and found that unit testing a realm object saving etc. isn't that straightforward!